# Setup RTL direction for only a specific widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to align label inside a TextField component to the right like "labelPlacement" on FormControlLabel

i know that we can use RTL library with mui-theme, but that's is for the entire application. i just would like to use it only for One TextField of the application

thanks

Comment: add textAlign property to your textfield style
styled={{ textAlign: 'right' }}

Comment: thanks @SarmadShah i tried that before but inot works. cause we use Material ui. so the solution have to take that we use Material ui for react

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textAlign` property to achieve this.

```
style={{
  textAlign: 'right'
}}
```

Use this indie `TextInput` or any other component you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution from github Material-ui repo.

by using custom style for the label inside root attribute : 
Here's a codesandbox demo  https://codesandbox.io/s/6vk85j86xr